# Proper way to draw gridlines

Tags: d3.js

Okay, I'm starting to get a little more familiar with D3 but am still a little hazy on some things. I'm now trying to draw grid lines but am realizing that I may be hacking away versus doing it correctly. I tried to add some gridlines, using a tutorial, but ended up with a lot of code that I seem to be jimmy rigging in order to get it to line up properly. I was wondering if anyone could point me to a better way of writing this...

The original code is this.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
            var w = 800;
            var h = 400;
            var padding = 20;
            var border=1;
            var bordercolor='black';


            var dataset = [
                            [5, 20], [480, 90], [250, 50], [100, 33], [330, 95],[-50,-100],[50,-45],
                            [410, 12], [475, 44], [25, 67], [85, 21], [220, 88],[-480, -467], [3,-90],[468,481]
                          ];

                // create scale functions
                var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                 .domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; }), d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
                                 .range([padding, w - padding * 2]);

            var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                 .domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; }), d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                                 .range([h - padding, padding]);

                var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain(  [-100,      d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1];            })]   )
                .range([2,5]);

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h)
                        .attr("border",border)
                        ;

            //define X axis   this is rly a function, remember, variables can hold functions in JS
                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(xScale)
                        .orient("bottom")
                        .ticks(1)
                        .tickSize(-h, 0, 0)
                        ;   //Set rough # of ticks


            //Define Y axis
                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(yScale)
                        .orient("left")
                        .ticks(1)
                        .tickSize(-w, 0, 0)
                        ;




                //create the circles
            svg.selectAll("circle")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("circle")
               .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d[0]);
               })
               .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d[1]);
               })
               .attr("r", 3);





  //   draw axes here
   svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis") //assign "axis" class
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) +")")
    .call(xAxis);



       svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis") //assign "axis" class
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)"       )
    .call(yAxis);
// end draw axes here
        </script>
```

and the code I added in the second link is here

```
var vis = svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)")


var rules = vis.append("svg:g").classed("rules", true)


rules.append("svg:g").classed("grid x_grid", true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(-20,"+h+")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(xScale)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(4)
      .tickSize(-h,0,0)
      .tickFormat("")
    )

rules.append("svg:g").classed("grid y_grid", true)
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yScale)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
      .tickSize(-w,0,0)
      .tickFormat("")
    )

rules.append("svg:g").classed("labels x_labels", true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(-20,"+ h +")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(xScale)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(4)
      .tickSize(0)
            .tickFormat("")
      // .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y/%m"))
    )

rules.append("svg:g").classed("labels y_labels", true)
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yScale)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
      .tickSubdivide(1)
      .tickSize(0, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
    )
```

Again, really appreciate any help

Answer (score 79):

Assuming that you have [Mike Bostock's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365814/mbostock) standard [margins](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563) defined and you have defined a linear scale for the y-axis the following code will create horizontal gridlines without using `tickSize()`.

```
svg.selectAll("line.horizontalGrid").data(yScale.ticks(4)).enter()
    .append("line")
        .attr(
        {
            "class":"horizontalGrid",
            "x1" : margin.right,
            "x2" : width,
            "y1" : function(d){ return yScale(d);},
            "y2" : function(d){ return yScale(d);},
            "fill" : "none",
            "shape-rendering" : "crispEdges",
            "stroke" : "black",
            "stroke-width" : "1px"
        });
```

Comment: Absolutely! This single attribute object can also be used with .style({...})

Comment: Would you mind explaining your motivation behind not using Ticksize and why your solution might be considered better practice?

Comment: Good idea setting data to `yScale.ticks` :)

Comment: I like this solution better than using tickSize because this allows me to have tickunits outside the plot area AND grid lines inside it, and even style them differently. So far I could not see how you would do that using tickSize.

Comment: the key-value object form of `attr` doesnt seem to work anymore with v4....

Comment: I'll take a quick look to see what needs to be changed. Do you have any references to the corresponding documentation for v4?

Comment: @arete, this solution works like charm but what if to display the grid line based on condition? like for example in the line chart i want to add threshold line(grid line)  at a certain position

Comment: In D3 v4 and v5 you cannot pass an object to `.attr` unless you include https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi (which is not part of the default bundle).

The solution is simple, just decompose it into several `.attr` calls, one for each attribute.

Answer (score 20):

I would suggest to use d3.svg.axis().scale() to tie up the grid to your coordinates. I drew a [quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/temirov/Rt65L/1/) based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/temirov/Rt65L/1/

[image: Grid example]

The gist is to use the existing scales, x and y, and to use ticks as grid. Since yAxis and xAxis are already defined we can just re-use them. Here is the relevant code:

```
//Draw a grid
var numberOfTicks = 6;

var yAxisGrid = yAxis.ticks(numberOfTicks)
    .tickSize(w, 0)
    .tickFormat("")
    .orient("right");

var xAxisGrid = xAxis.ticks(numberOfTicks)
    .tickSize(-h, 0)
    .tickFormat("")
    .orient("top");

svg.append("g")
    .classed('y', true)
    .classed('grid', true)
    .call(yAxisGrid);

svg.append("g")
    .classed('x', true)
    .classed('grid', true)
    .call(xAxisGrid);
```

Comment: +1 This is defo the best way to do it, as it means that if you change the .ticks() property on your axis, then it will be reflected in the grid lines.

Answer (score 12):

You could use the `ticks()` function of your scale to get the tick values and then use them in a data call to draw the lines.

```
var ticks = xScale.ticks(4);
rules.selectAll("path.xgrid").data(ticks).enter()
     .append("path")
     .attr("d", function(d) {
       return "M" + xScale(d) + " " + padding + "L" + xScale(d) + " " + (h-padding);
     });
```

You may prefer using a line generator for the grid lines instead of creating the path manually. This works similarly for y grid lines, only that the y coordinate is constant and ranges from 0 to width of graph. You may need to adjust the start and end values to make it look "nice".

Comment: I agree with Lars and have found using the ticks for gridlines useful as well. See here for a variant http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-grid-lines-to-d3js-graph.html

Comment: That was the link I used to create this version of my graph: http://goo.gl/OmX52  but I ended up having to manually mess with the "transform" to get the lines to match and it was still not perfectly in line. Lars, I copied your code into my <script> but I could not see any evidence of grid lines being drawn, the console that "rules" had not been defined.  I rly appreciate your help on helping to get familarised on this.

Comment: Okay, I see the reference to rules now, you were using the code I had on my 2nd link.

Answer (score 2):

In the d3fc project we have created a [gridlines component](https://d3fc.io/api/annotation-api.html#gridline) that renders in exactly the same way as the D3(v4) axis.

Here's an example of the usage:

```
var width = 500, height = 250;
var container = d3.select("#gridlines")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, 100]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, 100]);

var gridline = fc.annotationSvgGridline()
  .xScale(xScale)
  .yScale(yScale);

container.append("g")
  .call(gridline);
```

Which renders as follows:

[image]

The spacing of the gridlines is determined by the ticks supplied by the associated axes.

Disclosure: I am a core contributor to the d3fc project!

Answer (score 2):

Use `tickSizeInner()`

```
// x axis
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).domain([0, 100000]);
svg
  .append("g")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(10).tickSizeInner(-height))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @arete's idea, you can use the following to avoid re-drawing unnecessarily the gridline:

```
function createsGrid(data) {
       var grid = gridLine.selectAll("line.horizontalGrid").data(scaleY.ticks());

       grid.enter()
       .append("line")
       .attr("class","horizontalGrid");

       grid.exit().remove();

       grid.attr({
               "x1":0,
               "x2": width,
               "y1": function (d) { return scaleY(d); },
               "y2": function (d) { return scaleY(d); }
                });
}
```

and define the following in your CSS file

```
line.horizonalGrid{
  fill : none;
 shape-rendering : crispEdges;
 stroke : black;
 stroke-width : 1.5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use innerTickSize, instead of tickSize:

```
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .orient("bottom")
                    .ticks(1)
                    .innerTickSize(-h);
```