# Adding Grid to D3.js Line Chart

Tags: grid, d3.js, linechart

I have this Line Chart here:

jsfiddle.net/yfqQ4/

My Problem now is, that I don't get a proper grid in the background working with a legend (y and x-Axis) like this: http://lab.creativebrains.net/linechart.png

Can anybody can post me a code snippet how I should implement it or something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580300/proper-way-to-draw-gridlines) may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw background grid like this:

```
//vertical lines
svg.selectAll(".vline").data(d3.range(26)).enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", function (d) {
    return d * 20;
})
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
    return d * 20;
})
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
    return 0;
})
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
    return 500;
})
    .style("stroke", "#eee");

// horizontal lines
svg.selectAll(".vline").data(d3.range(26)).enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
    return d * 20;
})
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
    return d * 20;
})
    .attr("x1", function (d) {
    return 0;
})
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
    return 500;
})
    .style("stroke", "#eee");
```

You can see here how it works with your jsfiddle (updated): 
http://jsfiddle.net/cuckovic/Phzvy/

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest to use d3.svg.axis().scale() to tie up the grid to your coordinates. I drew a [quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/yfqQ4/5/) based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/yfqQ4/5/

[image]

The gist is to use the existing scales, x and y, and to use ticks as grid. Notice that `height` and `width` are the variable defining the size of your container. Here is the relevant code:

```
var numberOfTicks = 6;

var yAxisGrid = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .ticks(numberOfTicks) 
  .tickSize(width, 0)
  .tickFormat("")
  .orient("right");

var xAxisGrid = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .ticks(numberOfTicks) 
  .tickSize(-height, 0)
  .tickFormat("")
  .orient("top");

svg.append("g")
  .classed('y', true)
  .classed('axis', true)
  .call(yAxisGrid);

svg.append("g")
  .classed('x', true)
  .classed('axis', true)
  .call(xAxisGrid);
```