# D3JS — my X axis grid line isn't showing up

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I'm at a loss as to why my X axis lines are showing up perfectly fine, but not Y. Any ideas?

I'm 99% sure it has something to do with the

```
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
```

line since every time i adjust that it DOES show X axis pieces, just in the wrong space.

Entire code is as follows:

```
<html>

<head>

<style>

/* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path {
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2;
        fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.grid path {
      stroke: lightgrey;
      stroke-width: 0;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<h1>Temperature Chart Over Time</h1>

<script>
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var     margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Display the date and time
var     parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

// Set the X and Y axis ranges
var     x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var     y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the X and Y axes
var     xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(10);

var     yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
        .orient("left").ticks(10);

// Define the line
var     valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.measurementTime); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

        // Adds the svg canvas
var     svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Draw X axis grid tick marks
function make_x_axis() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
         .orient("bottom")
         .ticks(5)
}

//Draw Y axis grid tick marks
function make_y_axis() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(5)
}

//draw x axis grid lines
svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(make_x_axis()
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )
//draw y axis grid lines
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .call(make_y_axis()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

// Get the data
d3.json("data.php", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.measurementTime = parseDate(d.measurementTime);
                d.temperature = +d.temperature;
        });

        // Center the line on the graph
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.measurementTime; }));
        y.domain([60, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.temperature; })+10]);

         // Add the valueline path
        svg.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", valueline(data));

        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis);

});

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: I've attached a link to a *broken* jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uERXY/

Comment: I don’t think it’s the `translate`, because if you remove that whole line and change it to `orient('left')`, it draws the same thing. Am I correct in believing that you are looking for there to be 5 vertical lines but there are only 2?

Comment: @BuckDoyle yes, that's exactly what's up. It makes two lines—one on each end of the chart, but none in the middle. I've tried a bunch of different orientations myself.

Comment: @oshikryu thank you! This is a lot easier than messing around in nano.

Comment: You are creating two sets of axes in your code. Which one are you talking about? What does your data look like? Is is possible that your domain is set up incorrectly?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I am concerned with the parts that add axis grid marks and X axis tick marks. Everything else seems to be working fine.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly how you want it to be different from what you currently have please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I want there to be horizontal and vertical grid lines. Right now I'm only getting horizontal grid lines. Does that help?

Comment: Then [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-grid-lines-to-d3js-graph.html) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580300/proper-way-to-draw-gridlines) should help.